# Sinon js AssertError: expected stub to be called once but was called 0 times

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, sinon-chai

I have been learning Sinon JS for unit testing, and I am trying to get this example code working.  I have a simple "external" library created:

```
class MyLib {

   simpleMethod () {
      return 'some response';
   }

   static handler() {
      const myLib = new MyLib();
      myLib.simpleMethod();
   }
}

module.exports = MyLib;
```

Then, I have a simple test suite:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const MyLib = require('./my-lib');

describe ('sinon example tests', () => {

  it ('should call simpleMethod once', () => {
     let stubInstance = sinon.stub(MyLib, 'simpleMethod');

     MyLib.handler();

     sinon.assert.calledOnce(stubInstance);
  });

});
```

But I am returned with the error "AssertError: expected stub to be called once but was called 0 times".  I know this is probably obvious, but why is `simpleMethod` not being called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simpleMethod is an instance method. To stub an instance method, you should stub the prototype.

Try this in your code.

```
myStub = sinon.stub(MyLib.prototype, 'simpleMethod');
```

Remember to restore the stub at the end of the test.

```
myStub.restore();
```